# Understanding pg-pool in details

Tags: postgresql, replication, pgpool

I have following problem regarding the pg-pool (3.3.3)

1. When master fails, automatic failover happens and standby is promoted to master. But this new master don't have any replicators. Other slave servers still thinks as old master is their master and trying replicate from it.
2. Now insert is waiting indefinitely until synchronous replication happens. This wait is indefinite since now there's no replication happens from new master.

Is this the correct behaviour of pg-pool ?

Now in this setup I need to sync the old master manually and setup the replication. After everything setup pg-pool fails to find primary node. This primary node finding process success, after I comment **# - Backend Connection Settings -** on **pgpool.conf**, start pg-pool and again uncomment the connection settings, restart the pg-pool.

Comment: For question 2 got following answer.   http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74063/postgresql-synchronous-replication-time-out

Comment: You need to mention clear servers deployment, how many slave servers do you have ?
could you publish your pgpool.conf file from every server ?, have you configured postgres replication?, a good source of information available in http://pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Mailing_lists, with lots of questions and answers. Regards