# PostgreSQL synchronous replication time out?

Tags: postgresql, replication, pgpool

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 with synchronous replication. I have 2 synchronous replicators and 1 async replicator. My problem is when 2 synchronous replicators are down, transaction will wait indefinitely. 
I found following discussion about this,

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Timeout-for-asynchronous-replication-Re-Timeout-and-wait-forever-in-sync-rep-td3293679.html

but could not found a solution. Is there a way to resolve this problem ? ( may be using tool like pg-pool )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a problem, it's by design.

If you don't want transactions to wait until a synchronous replica acknowledges a commit, then you don't want synchronous replication. You want async replication and should simply remove the `synchronous_standby_names` option.

What good would synchronous replication be if it gave up when no replica was reachable? "I promise your transaction is safe on another node - oh, unless the replicas are down, in which case I'll silently break my promise."

Generally what you should be doing is setting [`synchronous_commit`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT) to `local` in transactions that don't care if the commit is synchronous, which the docs say means:

> However, the special value local is available for transactions that wish to wait for local flush to disk, but not synchronous replication.

and leaving it as `on` for important transactions you can't afford to lose. So only those will wait until a standby is available to replicate the changes.

See also the docs on [`synchronous_standby_names`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-STANDBY-NAMES).

Now, you might want a way to say "Wait for up to 5 minutes for a standby to acknowledge, but proceed anyway if it hasn't by then." That's not currently supported. I'm not really convinced it's useful either.

Comment: Of course such a feature is highly useful! You want a guarantee of synchronous commits so that you can failover to node B if the primary goes down. But you also want to be tolerate failures if node A goes down.

Comment: @Otheus That's a cluster management decision - there's no one right thing to do and PostgreSQL can't know what you want. If you decide that the replica is down, you clear synchronous_standby_names and reload the master config. I guess it'd be nice to have a final "dummy" name like "ignore" allowable in synchronous_standby_names, so Pg tries to wait for replay but gives up eventually and ignores the failure while yelling for help in the logs. Patches are welcome ;)

Comment: I'll take this up with you in PG mailing lists :)

Comment: There should be a feature which should say "disable synchronous replication when un-able to reach or delay with other node, bring it up when the node is up and reachable with-in time period". This is what mysql does with "semi-sync-repliation". I understand that is different than "sync-replication" still that shouldn't timeout and reject a transaction if other node which I consider as slave actually and part of synchronous replication.

Comment: What if someone wants the transaction to fail if the secondary can't be reached?

Answer (score 1):

No it should'nt. You misunderstood what synchronous replication means. Synchronous mean than you should have at least one copy at any time no matter what. If you don't then use asynchronous replication. Postgres is semi-sync replication by design if you use replication slots. Replication in Postgres is so much better than in MySQL, in fact MySQL has terrible replication features like "skip". MySQL does not guarantee that your data is correctly replicated even with "row replication", you have to use Percona tools on regulary basis to check consistency between Master and Slave.